# Sync GCP PostgreSQL tables to GCP BigQuery

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We are currently using Stitchdata to periodically sync data over from a PostgreSQL instance to a BigQuery instance. The data is used for building reports. Stitchdata allows a pipeline to be built with a few checkboxes and options without the need for coding.

I am wondering if Google Cloud Platform offers a solution to allow a PostgreSQL database (hosted with GCP) to be synced to a BigQuery table. This is for the purpose of data sovereignty and user data privacy issues.

We do not want to use `federated queries` since we only want certain columns to be imported to BigQuery from PostgreSQL.

I have looked at:

- Datastream + Data Fusion (Datastream does not support Postgres yet)
- BigQuery Data Transfer + Fivetran Postgres Connector (This will cause the data to be transferred to third-party processor.)
- Data Fusion (Replication is not supported for PostgreSQL)

I am curious if I am missing anything glaring obvious with what Google Cloud Platform offers to sync data from our PostgreSQL database into BgigQuery.

Cheers

Comment: Can you explain why  you don't want to use federated table? This is the best solution, you query the data (and the columns) that you want in Cloud SQL, and then you load them in BigQuery table (or you merge them to remove duplicates). Can you tell us more?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I was mainly thinking:
- automated process that syncs tables from PG into BQ. (At least data changes, don't care so much about deletions.)
- then create views in BQ without sensitive columns from the source table, and share these views to different departments to enable them to create their own dashboards.

federated query has some limitations and we would rather not hit the production PG with additional loads

Comment: You will add load with any solutions. Is it possible to add a read replicas to request it instead of the main server?

Comment: @Bill were you able to find a solution for you issue? I am trying to do something very similar.

Comment: @user2491463 no I have not found a native/managed GCP solution yet. I did reach out to GCP's support, and they've mentioned that support for replication from PostgreSQL to BQ is coming soon. However, no timelines.

Comment: As @guillaumeblaquiere said, "you will add load with any solutions." It sounds like you basically want to set up an ELT pipeline. Is there a reason you can't write a light stored procedure to Extract the data you need from a federated query and load it into BQ tables? From there, you can transform for your various stakeholders as you mentioned. I do this every day with dbt but it wouldn't be much more difficult with a simple SP.

Comment: @Bill hi, have you found a pipeline to use it? Datastream does support Postgres but currently, in its pre-GA state it has multiple breaking limitations, for example not accepting ENUM-type fields and such. We got the pipeline working quite fast with Datastream only to figure out the limitations when the data arrived in BQ missing some columns.

Comment: @MorenoMdz I am in the same boat. Datastream has limitations, working with our GCP account manager to see if the issues will be addressed. We are still using Stitch Data for the sync.

Answer (score 0):

GCP Datastream supports now CDC from PostgreSQL to BigQuery. There are currently some issues which we have experienced though. For example, it's not possible to use partitioned tables on BigQuery side, bcs Datastream creates them and we don't have control over this operation. If we are synchronizing a really big tables from PostgreSQL and then building some ETLs, we will scan a lot of data.